# Parsing into another xml format

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I found many xml parsing examples, but they can not help me with my special xml format.
Here is an example of my unusual xml format

> ```
> <states xsi:type="auto:InitialState" name="Anfang"/>
> <act name="Megadon" start="//@states.2" end="//@states.3"/>
> ```

Unfortunately I can not work with it, I need the xml format like:

> ```
> <states> <xsi:type>auto:InitialState</xsi:type> <name>Anfang</name> </states>
> <act> <name>Megadon</name> <start>//@states.2</start> <end>//@states.3</end> </act>
> ```

Is there a way to do this without complex String operations?

Comment: Why can't you use standard XML APIs, or possibly an XSLT ? I wouldn't begin to attempt this via String operations

Comment: As @BrianAgnew says. XSLT is the way to go.

Comment: [Oracle XSLT Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html) is probably the best place to start it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. So this format is not xml, but xsl? I checked it out, but still dont understand how big the effort for the transormation is. Can this XSLT tool do all the work for itself, want to say I give as input the xsl file and it gives me as output the xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is nothing "special" or "unusual" about your XML. It's bog-standard. In fact, the alternative form is rather unusual and non-standard, because xsi:type is defined in the standards as an attribute (your first form), not as an element (your second form).

It's easy to transform the first form to the second using XSLT. XSLT is a language that allows you to specify a set of transformation rules. For example the rule

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:element name="name()" namespace="{namespace-uri()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

will convert attributes to elements (which is what you want to do).